How to supress scientific notation in only one column of a dataframe
I have a dataframe where each column is floats rounded to different specific number of decimal places and a timestamp column. The timestamp column also prints in scientific notation.
I want to print the last 5 rows of the dataframe and suppress the scientific notation for only the ts column. The solutions I see only change the formatting for the entire dataframe and not the specific column.
I can provide an example...
print(df[-5:])
               ts    data1   data2
467  1.713263e+09  1005.52  5242.8
468  1.713263e+09  3527.83  5227.1
469  1.713263e+09  4079.06  5228.8
470  1.713263e+09  5079.43  3478.9
471  1.713263e+09  5224.44  3059.2

but I want
             ts    data1   data2
467  1713263525  1005.52  5242.8
468  1713263526  3527.83  5227.1
469  1713263527  4079.06  5228.8
470  1713263528  5079.43  3478.9
471  1713263529  5224.44  3059.2


Or out = df.assign(ts = lambda x: x['ts'].apply('{:.0f}'.format))
